# Conformal mapping form triangle region to disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following problem, let $D$ be:

$$
D=\{
z
\in\mathbb{C}:
\vert
Arg(z)
\vert
\leq
\frac{\pi}{4}
\}
-[1,\infty)
$$

Then the question is: Does it exists a real number $R\in\mathbb{R}$ so that there is a conformal mapping, $f$ between $D$ and $D(0,R)$ so that
$f(\frac{1}{2})=0$ and $f'(\frac{1}{2})=1$.

Since both regions are simply connected is quite clear that a conformal mapping exits, and that by scaling this conformal mapping we can get the condition on $f'$ satisfied. However, I don't know how to calculate this map.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_1(z) = 1/z^4$ maps $D$ conformally onto $D_1 = \Bbb C  \setminus (-\infty , 1]$, with $f_1(1/2) = 16$.

Then $f_2(z) = \sqrt{z-1}$ maps $D_1$ conformally onto the right halfplane (with the principal value of the square root), with $f_2(16) = \sqrt {15}$.

Finally, $f_3(z) = (z-\sqrt {15})/(z + \sqrt {15})$ maps the right halfplane conformally onto the unit disk, with $f_3(\sqrt {15}) = 0$.

Comment: But $0$ is in D, so $f_1$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Nevermind, it is not